# Why is my ISTIO policy configuration not applied?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am using Istio-1.0.6 to implement Authentication/Authorization. I am attempting to use Jason Web Tokens (JWT). I followed most of the examples from the documentation but I am not getting the expected outcome. Here are my settings:

Service

```
kubectl describe services hello
Name:              hello
Namespace:         agud
Selector:          app=hello
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.247.173.177
Port:              <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         172.16.0.193:8080
Session Affinity:  None
```

Gateway

```
kubectl describe gateway
Name:         hello-gateway
Namespace:    agud
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  Cluster Name:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-03-15T13:40:43Z
  Resource Version:    1374497
  Self Link:           
/apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/agud/gateways/hello-gateway
  UID:                 ee483065-4727-11e9-a712-fa163ee249a9
Spec:
  Selector:
    Istio:  ingressgateway
  Servers:
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      http
      Number:    80
      Protocol:  HTTP
```

Virtual Service

```
kubectl describe virtualservices
Name:         hello
Namespace:    agud
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         VirtualService
Metadata:
  Cluster Name:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-03-18T07:38:52Z
  Generation:          0
  Resource Version:    2329507
  Self Link:           
/apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/agud/virtualservices/hello
  UID:                 e099b560-4950-11e9-82a1-fa163ee249a9
Spec:
  Gateways:
    hello-gateway
  Hosts:
    *
  Http:
    Match:
      Uri:
        Exact:  /hello
      Uri:
        Exact:  /secured
    Route:
      Destination:
        Host:  hello.agud.svc.cluster.local
        Port:
          Number:  8080
```

Policy

```
kubectl describe policies
Name:         jwt-hello
Namespace:    agud
API Version:  authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Policy
Metadata:
  Cluster Name:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-03-18T07:45:33Z
  Generation:          0
  Resource Version:    2331381
  Self Link:           
/apis/authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/agud/policies/jwt-hello
  UID:                 cf9ed2aa-4951-11e9-9f64-fa163e804eca
Spec:
  Origins:
    Jwt:
      Audiences:
        hello
      Issuer:         testing@secure.istio.io
      Jwks Uri:       https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.0/security/tools/jwt/samples/jwks.json
  Principal Binding:  USE_ORIGIN
  Targets:
    Name:  hello.agud.svc.cluster.local
```

RESULT

I am expecting to get a 401 error but I am getting a 200. What is wrong with my configuration and how do I fix this?

```
curl $INGRESS_HOST/hello -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"
200
```

Comment: please make it simpler by providing the yaml files instead of the describe command

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
Port:              <unset>  8080/TCP
```

For *Istio routing and security*, you must set the port name to `http` or `http-<something>`.

I tried with Istio 1.1. I got a `503` rather than a `401`.

Comment: Hi @esnible, I added the port 8080 but that did not help.

Comment: Your Kubernetes service "hello" will have a Port.  In Kubernetes the ports have a name field but it is merely a label.  The name is meaningful for Istio.  Try `kubectl edit` your hello Service and give the port the name `http`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help too. kubectl describe service hello
Name:              hello
Namespace:         agud
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=hello
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.247.174.223
Port:              http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         172.16.0.163:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>